# Examples of sequences in lp spaces

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Give an example of a sequence in $l^{1}$ that:

1) converges a zero in $l^{\infty}$ but is not bounded in $l^{2}$;

2) converges a zero in $l^{2}$ but is not bounded in $l^{1}$.

Can anyone help me?

I thought to use these sequences

$$1) x(n)=\frac{e_n}{n^{1/3}}$$

$$2) x(n)=\frac{1}{n}$$

Are they correct?

Comment: A sequence in $l^{1}$ is a sequence of sequences. You are just defining single seqeunces.

Answer (score 3):

For 1) define $a_{n,j}=\frac 1 n$ for $j\leq n^{3}$ and $0$ otherwise. For 2) define $a_{n,j}=\frac 1 j$ for $n\leq j\leq n^{2}$ and $0$ otherwise. The sequences $a_n=(a_{n,j})$, $n=1,2,\cdots$ have the required properties. For 2) you need the fact that $\sum_n^{n^{2}}\frac 1 j \to \infty$. For this compare with the integral $\int_n^{n^{2}} \frac 1 x\, dx$ which is $\log\, n$.

Comment: Thank you! Do you think is correct the sequence I wrote for the first part?

Comment: @MartiCrep no.Your suggestions are two sequence of real numbers that may or not belong to some/all/non $\ell^p$.

You are looking for a sequence of sequences.